# Frame Conventions for Interactive Markers

Tags: ros, visualization-msgs, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can attach Markers to the controls in InteractiveMarkers. The [InteractiveMarker](http://docs.ros.org/api/visualization_msgs/html/msg/InteractiveMarker.html) has its own Header/frame_id as does the [Marker](http://docs.ros.org/api/visualization_msgs/html/msg/Marker.html) attached to the [InteractiveMarkerControl](http://docs.ros.org/api/visualization_msgs/html/msg/InteractiveMarkerControl.html).

If you publish two InteractiveMarkers that are completely identical except for the InteractiveMarker's frame_id, you get two different behaviors.

Let's say there's a moving frame called "up" and a stationary frame called "world."  We want to put a marker at the up frame, so we create a simple box Marker with the frame_id "up". To make an interactive marker of this is easy, but you have the choice of whether to have the InteractiveMarker's frame_id be up or world.

If its up, then the marker will move with the frame up. However, if the IM's frame is "world", then the marker will NOT move with the frame.

This phenomenon is illustrated by [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZtqOsawrf5k) and the following code.

Question: Is there some hidden semantics that I'm missing here, or is this just a bug?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import roslib; roslib.load_manifest("interactive_markers")
import rospy
from visualization_msgs.msg import *
from interactive_markers.interactive_marker_server import *
from tf import TransformBroadcaster
import tf.transformations

def make_marker(frame, color):
    int_marker = InteractiveMarker()
    int_marker.header.frame_id = frame
    int_marker.name = frame

    box_marker = Marker()
    box_marker.type = Marker.CUBE
    box_marker.scale.x = 0.5
    box_marker.scale.y = 0.05
    box_marker.scale.z = 0.05
    box_marker.color.r = color[0]
    box_marker.color.g = color[1]
    box_marker.color.b = color[2]
    box_marker.color.a = 1.0
    box_marker.header.frame_id = '/up'

    box_control = InteractiveMarkerControl()
    box_control.always_visible = True
    box_control.markers.append( box_marker )
    int_marker.controls.append( box_control )
    return int_marker

if __name__=="__main__":
    rospy.init_node("simple_marker")
    server = InteractiveMarkerServer("r2_teleop")
    
    server.insert(make_marker('/up', (0,0,1)))
    server.insert(make_marker('/world', (0,1,0)))
    server.applyChanges()
    
    tfx = TransformBroadcaster()
    start = rospy.Time.now()
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        x = (rospy.Time.now()-start).to_sec()
        yaw = (x % 10.0)*3.14*2/10.0
        tfx.sendTransform((0, 0, 0.5),
                     tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0, 0, yaw),
                     rospy.Time.now(),
                     'up',
                     "world")
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186866/frame-conventions-for-interactive-markers/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2014-07-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-07-16**:
ROS has no bugs, only "undocumented features"!. LOL sorry for the useless comment, just had to say it :P Probably we just need to be careful to set the Marker frame_id and the InteractiveMarker frame_id to the same value. But don't take my word, I have no authority on the matter whatsoever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is descibed in the InteractiveMarkerControl mesage definition:

http://docs.ros.org/api/visualization_msgs/html/msg/InteractiveMarkerControl.html

```
# Markers to be displayed as custom visual representation.
# Leave this empty to use the default control handles.
#
# Note: 
# - The markers can be defined in an arbitrary coordinate frame,
#   but will be transformed into the local frame of the interactive marker.
# - If the header of a marker is empty, its pose will be interpreted as 
#   relative to the pose of the parent interactive marker.
Marker[] markers
```

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2014-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2